# EC2 instance running S3 Sync command terminates before data transfer is complete

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization, replication

I have an EC2 instance running Linux. This instance is used to run `aws s3` commands.

I want to sync the last 6 months worth of data from `source` to `target` S3 buckets. I am using credentials with the necessary permissions to do this.

Initially I just ran the command:

```
aws s3 sync "s3://source" "s3://target" --query "Contents[?LastModified>='2022-08-11' && LastModified<='2023-01-11']"
```

However, after maybe 10 mins this command stops running, and only a fraction of the data is synced.

I thought this was because my SSM session was terminating, and with it the command stopped executing.

To combat this, I used the following command to try and ensure that this command would continue to execute even after my SSM terminal session was closed:

```
nohup aws s3 sync "s3://source" "s3://target" --query "Contents[?LastModified>='2022-08-11' && LastModified<='2023-01-11']" --exclude "*.log" --exclude "*.bak" &
```

Checking the status of the EC2 instance, the command appears to run for about 20 mins, before clearly stopping for some reason.

[image: Instance Monitoring]

Comment: What does the nohup.out file show you?

Answer (score 0):

The `--query` parameter controls what information is displayed in the response from an API call.

It **does not** control which files are copied in an `aws s3 sync` command. The [documentation for `aws s3 sync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) defines the `--query` parameter as: *"A JMESPath query to use in filtering the response data."*

Your `aws s3 sync` command will be synchronizing *ALL* files unless you use [Exclude and Include Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters). These filters operate on the *name* of the object. It is *not* possible to limit the `sync` command by supplying date ranges.

I cannot comment on why the command would stop running before it is complete. I suggest you redirect output to a log file and then review the log file for any clues.